# Postgres ltree with variables in query

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, ltree

I use variable in psql like: `\set user_id 10;`

When i want use this variable in query like `select * from users where user_id = :user_id;` - it's ok

But when i use this for ltree column i have a problem `select * from accounts where customer_id <@ :user_id`?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a string literal, so you have to quote the value:

```
select * from accounts where customer_id <@ :'user_id';
```

That will become

```
select * from accounts where customer_id <@ '10';
```

Comment: thank you! it's work!